# django url testing case

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, I am following one tutorial for learning, everything went fine after writing the testing cases it's showing some error, I am following as per tutorial don't know why it's not working.

Run python manage.py test

Output:

```html
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_home_url_resolves_home_view (boards.tests.HomeTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sradha\Development\myproject\myproject\boards\tests.py", line 13, in test_home_url_resolves_home_view
    view = resolve('/')
  File "C:\Users\sradha\Development\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 24, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "C:\Users\sradha\Development\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 520, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>], [<URLPattern 'homepage/' [name='home']>]], 'path': ''}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.036s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

tests.py  file

```html
from django.urls import reverse
from django.urls import resolve
from django.test import TestCase
from .views import home

class HomeTests(TestCase):
    def test_home_view_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('home')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_home_url_resolves_home_view(self):
        view = resolve('/')
        self.assertEquals(view.func, home)
```

urls.py

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from boards import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('homepage/', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

python version  3.6.2
django version  2.1.1

thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial?

Comment: I think the `resolve(..)` here should be given `'homepage/'`, so you might have made a mistake in the `urls.py`.

Comment: Would you mind to show your `urls.py` file?

Comment: @nik_m please have a look , I edited my code

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html

this is the link @nik_m

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html    @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @sradha: the path should be `path('', views.home, name='home'),`, so an empty string as first element.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have any URL on `/` only on `/admin/...` and `/homepage` in your urls.py.

So you would have to change `resolve('/')` to `resolve('/homepage/')`

Answer (score 0):

In the `test.py` file, you have to make changes to resolve the argument.

```
def test_home_url_resolves_home_view(self):

    view = resolve('/homepage/')
    self.assertEquals(view.func, home)
```

Below is the link to the tutorial: [Django tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html) for reference.